# How do i add another button on modal footer of antdesign?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to add another button on the Modal footer. How can i do it? In the documents you can only edit the ok and cancel buttons, but doesn't have a docs on how to add another button.

Comment: There is a customised footer example in [docs](https://ant.design/components/modal/) itself

Comment: there is but you can only update the props of the button :(

Comment: [Customised Footer](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-cookies-mh193) example, not the Custom Footer props one

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `footer` property of [`Modal`](https://ant.design/components/modal/#API) which accepts an array of components.

```js
      <Modal
        visible={true}
        footer={[
          <Button key="1">1</Button>,
          <Button key="2">2</Button>,
          <Button key="3" type="primary">
            3
          </Button>
        ]}
      >
        <p>Some contents...</p>
      </Modal>
```

[image: Edit OS Q 56474989]

Comment: What about a way to do this while preserving existing buttons and their default functionality? Like, I'd like to add it to the left side of the footer.

Comment: You can render anything... So just use some layout like flexbox.

Comment: Right, but that requires me to override all the existing render method, and rebuild the existing stuff.